# Copied Excel sheets using VBA is corrupted when reopened

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making a project where I have stored two sheets as templates for others to fill in, when this project is done. These two templates are hidden with Worksheets("..").Visible = False in the original file.

As my attempt to make this nice was to make two templates and hide them whereas when they want to add a templete (usually several) this hidden sheet will be copied and renamed like below:

```html
If OptionButton2.Value = False Then
        'kopiera mall 4v
        Worksheets("Mall 4v").Visible = True
        Worksheets("Mall 5v").Visible = True
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Copy after:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.name = month & " - " & name
        fourWeeks month, name, startWeek
        Worksheets("Mall 4v").Visible = False
        Worksheets("Mall 5v").Visible = False
Else
        ....
```

Where I utilize that copied sheets are activated by default. As you may have guessed this copy is made with the help of a UserForm (if that matters).

And now to the problem, if I save this right after this copy is made it can be re-opened withpout a problem but when something is put in the new sheet it gets corrupted every time. Allso I have three junksheets in the VBA-menu (former copied sheets that got corrupted) that I can't seem to remove or see any propertys, however the code can be found in them.

Comment: Download [VBA Cleaner](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm).  It should fix the old corrupt worksheets.  Are there controls on the copied worksheets?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out what's causing the problem:

In the copied file I have a ComboBox with several strings which is put in a cell when chosen and one of these strings also generates a Data Validation List in another cell. The code for this is given below:

```html
Public Sub DDlist(ByVal week As Integer, ByVal day As Integer, ByVal indexOffset As Integer, ByVal Page As Integer)
    Dim dvList As String

    dvList = " Item 1, Item 2"

    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(week + day + indexOffset, 3 + Page), Cells(week + day + indexOffset, 6 + Page)).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=dvList
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

(Not actually Item 1 and Item 2)
I suppose I can remove this feature but I really like the way it works and would like to keep it..

Hope this input can help solving the problem

Comment: Is DDlist in a public module or the worksheet module?

Comment: It's in the sheet, which also means it's in the copied sheet. I'm rather new to VBA, only done stuff out of interest so I'm not sure what modules are

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet is not needed because it is implied.  Select the new worksheet then press ctrl+F3.  This will bring up the Name Manager.  See if there are any references to the original workbook.

Comment: Name Manager is empty.

Comment: I'm thinking about an alternate solution to this problem, I dont know how to do it yet but I guess the Data Validation List can be removed after an item is chosen. Do you think this would fix the problem? Since the problem seem to be some reference error to the DV list.

Comment: You can remove all the validations from your templates using `Worksheets(?).Cells.Validation.Delete`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

After an item was chosen from dvlist the dvlist itself was removed with:

```html
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Selection.Validation.Delete
End Sub
```